# Poisson integral on circle with jump discontinuity

Tags: complex-analysis

This is related to a problem in Ahlfors' Complex Analysis book.
Let $U(z)$ be piecewise continuous on $|z| = 1$ with a jump discontinuity at $\alpha = e^{i\psi}$ where $|\alpha| = 1$, such that
$$
\lim_{\theta \to \psi_-}U(e^{i\theta}) = 1 \ 
\text{and}
\lim_{\theta \to \psi_+}U(e^{i\theta}) = 0
$$
Let
$$
P_U(z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1-|z|^2}{|e^{i\theta}-z|^2}U(e^{i\theta}) \ d\theta
$$
be the Poisson integral for $|z| < 1$.

**Question:** What can be said about $P_U(z)$ as $z$ approaches $\alpha$?

I tried to work out some sort of answer in a couple of different ways.
First, I tried to apply a corresponding result for the Poisson integral in the upper plane, changing variables using a fractional linear transformation. With this attempt, I came up with:

$$
\lim_{z \to \alpha} P_U(z)-\frac{1}{\pi}\arg\left(-i\frac{z-\alpha}{z+\alpha}\right) = 0
$$

Then, I tried to work it out directly from the integral on the unit circle, and came up with

$$
\lim_{z \to \alpha} P_U(z)-\frac{1}{\pi}\arg\left(\frac{\alpha - z}{\sqrt{\alpha}(1-z)}\right) = 0
$$

I am bothered by this, because they appear different in form.
I would like to know whether or not either one of these is correct, so that I can attempt to diagnose my failure for the incorrect one(s).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct, but the first is more correct than the second. The drawback of the second formula is that you one has to worry about choosing the sign of $\sqrt{\alpha}$ to make the values fit $U$.

Approximately, $z-\alpha \approx i t\alpha$ with $t$ real and small (I replaced the circle with its tangent line). This asymptotic captures the behavior of argument correctly. Also, $z+\alpha$ is about $2\alpha$, which turns the first formula into
$$-i\frac{z-\alpha}{z+\alpha} \approx \frac{t}{2}$$
The argument is either $0$ or $\pi$ depending on the sign of $t$, which is what you wanted.

The second formula takes longer to digest. Probably the easiest way is to draw the triangle with vertices $0,e^{i\psi},1$ and consider its angles. Then you will see why $1-z$ (which is about $1-\alpha$) naturally goes with $\sqrt{\alpha}$. Algebraically: 
$$(1-\alpha)^2 = \alpha(\alpha+\alpha^{-1}-2) = \alpha(2\cos t-2)$$
where the last factor is real. This is why the argument of $\sqrt{\alpha}(1-\alpha)$ is $\arg \alpha + \pi/2$ mod  $\pi$.

There are infinitely many harmonic functions with the desired form of jump at $\alpha$; any of them, when subtracted from $P_U$, will allow you to reduce the problem to the Poisson integral of a continuous function.

Comment: Thanks. I keep on getting $\arg (\sqrt{\alpha}(1-\alpha)) = \arg{\alpha}$ mod $\pi/2$ but I might just be goofing up.

Comment: @bryanj Actually you are right: there's an $i$ hidden in there, this is why you don't have $i$ explicitly in the second version.